# Probabilities of a Binary String

Tags: probability, binary

You generate a random $N$-bit binary string, and compute $X = \Sigma_1^N x_i$, where the $x_i$ are the $0$ and $1$ entries of the string.

- What is the probability that $X$ is odd, if $N$ is odd?
- What is the probability that $X$ is odd, if $N$ is even?

I've been told that the first part is easy, but can't seem to figure out even that. I've tried figuring out the probability for $N-1$ to be odd as a starting point, but can't figure out even that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Whatever the first $N-1$ bits are, the probability that $X$ is odd is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Nicolas I thought about that, but wasn't sure if that was actually true. Imagine if you have 9 bits. N - 1 is 8 bits, so on average you should get 4 bits that have 1s, which would be even, right?

Comment: Whether the sum of the first $N-1$ bits is odd or even, since the last bit is equally likely to be $0$ or $1$, the full sum is equally likely to be odd as it is to be even.

Comment: Ah, I see. Now it kind of makes sense intuitively, but how would you go about "proving" it? And also, doesn't that imply that part 1 and part 2 are both 50%?

Comment: Yes it does imply that. One can make the argument more formal by conditioning on the result of the first $N-1$ tosses. That is the more probabilistic way, But one can also do an induction on $N$. The base case is obvious, and if the sum of the first $k$ tosses is equally likely to be even as odd, it is easy to show that the sum of the first $k+1$ tosses is equally likely to be even as odd.